# How to describe the value for "remoteJenkinsFileSCM()" in the "remoteJenkinsFileWorkflowMultiBranchProjectFactory" context?

Tags: jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

Trying to define a groovy dsl script to generate a "Github Organization Folder" job configuration using "Remote File Plugin" to define a centralized Jenkinsfile

```
organizationFolder("${org}") {
    description('This contains branch source jobs for Bitbucket and GitHub')
    displayName("${org}")
    triggers {
        cron('@daily')
    }
    organizations {
        github {
            repoOwner("${org}")
            credentialsId('myCreds')
            apiUri('myGithubUr')
        }
    }
    projectFactories {
        remoteJenkinsFileWorkflowMultiBranchProjectFactory {
            localFile('something')
            remoteJenkinsFile('Jenkinsfile')
            matchBranches(false)
            remoteJenkinsFileSCM()
        }
    }
}
```

Not sure what value to pass "remoteJenkinsFileSCM()" in the code above, would like to have "Git" as the option selected in the configuration. An example would be really helpful and appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the UI to configure the job manually. Then look at the job's `config.xml` and translate that to Job DSL. The mapping between XML elements and Job DSL syntax should be very similar. Use the embedded Job DSL API viewer as a reference for the exact syntax.

The Remote File plugin page contains an example for configuring the job manually, see https://plugins.jenkins.io/remote-file. To get the `config.xml`, just add `config.xml` to the job page URL, e.g. `http://localhost:8080/job/example/config.xml`. You need to use Chrome to view that page.

Comment: Using the embedded Job DSL API viewer helped to get the actual syntax I was looking for. Thanks a lot @daspilker